# GXT/GWT widget for the 'object' tag

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

Is there a widget that is synonymous with the '<object>' tag or can I just use a HTML tag with object:

I was thinking of this but it is not idiomatic:

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTML;
final HTML h = new HTML("<object width='100%' height='100%' data='/media/invoice1.pdf'></object>");
        container.setCenterWidget(h);


<object width='100%' height='100%' data='/media/invoice1.pdf'></object>
```

This is with gxt 3.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any gwt widget wrapping the `object` tag, but you have the `ObjectElement` which you can use to create the element and attach it to the document:

```
  // Create an element and programatically set its attributes
  ObjectElement o = Document.get().createObjectElement();
  o.setWidth("100%");
  o.setHeight("100%");
  o.setData("/media/invoice1.pdf");

  // Attach the element to the document
  Document.get().getBody().appendChild(o);

  // Optionally you could wrap your element into a widget.
  Widget w = HTMLPanel.wrap(o);
```